# Google Analytics - Goals setup regular expression match

Tags: google-analytics, url

I have urls like the following:

- `http://example.com/item/1`
- `http://example.com/item/1341`
- `http://example.com/item/33324`

I want to set up a funnel in Google Analytics and I understand that I can use a regular expression.

What would i enter to match all the above URLs i.e `/item/#{id}`?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, assuming you want matches to only /item/#### and not allow /item/ (without a number), you should use:

`/item/[0-9]+`

Answer (score 2):

```
/item/[0-9]*
```

should do it. You can test it out by using the Find URL field at the bottom of the Top Content report (old analytics) or on the Site Content->Pages report on the new interface you can do an advanced filter and enter it as a regular expression.